# Draw on SurfaceView outside onDraw() Event

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a custom class `DrawingView` which extends `SurfaceView`. All the drawing is currently happening in the `onTouchEvent()`-Event. So how can I draw something on my SurfaceView outside the `onTouchEvent`?

I defined the DrawingView like this in my activity_main.xml:

```
<com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath.DrawingView
android:id="@+id/surface"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

and I tried this in my MainActivity:

```
DrawingView dV = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
Canvas canv = dV.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
canv.drawPoint(5,5,paint);
dV.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canv);
```

But I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Any tips here how i can draw on a surfaceView outside the onTouchEvent ?

---

So my DrawingView which extends SurfaceView now implements the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface.
So in the different constructors i add the Callback event like this:

```
    public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}
```

And in the onSurfaceCreated Event i render the image like this:

```
    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    render(holder);
}
```

But this is still inside the DrawingView class. How can i move the drawing part outside the DrawingView class to my main activity? E.G. i want to render my image on button click. I still found nothing on google how i can do this. Maybe it isn't the right way to use a surfaceview? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Where is the NPE happening?  What's null?  Are you waiting for the `surfaceCreated()` callback to fire?  For some examples, see Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  The MultiSurfaceActivity does some trivial animation off the UI thread.

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint. Now my MainActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback and in the surfaceCreated event i do this:

`code                DrawingView dV = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        Canvas canv = dV.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canv.drawText("Hello World",5,25,50,100,paint);
        dV.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canv);
        dV.invalidate();
`

Now i don't get an error but also nothing happens on my surfaceview